# $this->getChildHtml('custom_block') is not working

Tags: magento-1.6

I used below code in `base/default/layout/namespace_module.xml`

```
<review_product_list>
        <block name="product.review.form" >
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_block" template="namespace/module/form.phtml"/>
        </block>
</review_product_list>
```

And on `base/default/template/review/form.phtml`

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_block');
```

This code is also not working. Do you have idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your layout update is wrong except for the fact that your custom block does not contains `alias`(`as`) attribute which is actually we are using in parent template in order to refer a child block inside `getChildHtml()` function.ie your layout should looks like this.

```
<review_product_list>
        <reference name="product.review.form" >
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_block" as="custom_form_block" template="namespace/module/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</review_product_list>
```

So there are two changes.

1) You need to use a `reference` to the block with name `product.review.form` in your layout update.

2) You need to include `as` property to your custom block with name `custom_block`.

Now you need to call your custom block in `app/design/frontend/<pockage>/<theme>/template/review/form.phtml` like this

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_form_block'); ?>
```

Please note I Have used `as` property value inside `getChildHtml()` function.

In order to ensure the working of your layout update, you need to do one more thing. **Your module should load only after the core module `Mage_Review`** . In order to ensure it, you need to do a small update here

File : `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Modulename.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename> <!--replace this with your extension name -->
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool> <!-- put the correct codepool where your module resides -->
            <depends>
                <Mage_Review />
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Please note the `depends` parts. This small update will do rest job for you.

At last, clear cache and reload the page again. Bingo.. You see your template right ?

Comment: thanks for reply, but this not work too.
I am not able to understand why

Comment: you did everything that I have described? also make sure your custom block template file does exist. It should be in the location `app/design/frontend/<pckage>/<theme>/template/namespace/module/form.phtml`

Comment: also make sure your layout update should come inside `<layout><!-- code comes here--></layout>`

Comment: yes, I used this one, `<layout version="0.1.0">
<review_product_list>
        <reference name="product.review.form" >
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_block" as="custom_form_block" template="namespace/module/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</review_product_list>
</layout>`

Comment: then most probably magento is not recognizing your layout update file. show your module's `config.xml` file

Comment: `<frontend>
 <layout>
            <updates>
                <namespace_module>
                    <file>namespace_module.xml</file>
                </namespace_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>`
I used this code to update layout xml file

Comment: I cant see any error in that code too. Look for any log errors !!!! var/log folder

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy. I have not seen any error on log file too...

Answer (score 0):

You have missing reference tag .To align a block into a block you need to put `reference` tag  and `this block reference name`

```
 <reference name="product.review.form" >
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_block" template="namespace/module/form.phtml"/>
        </reference >
```

Comment: I have already tried it and not worked, Now I tried this again but not working